# react-native-incall-manager speaker on/off not working on android 11

Tags: android, react-native

react-native-incall-manager setSpeakerphoneOn/setForceSpeakerphoneOn not working on android 11
when set speaker, the earphone sounds a little bit less, and the speaker no sound.
android 10 is working well.

Comment: I am facing the same issue with this package. Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-incall-manager/issues/164#issuecomment-862157563
It's worked well for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updated the setSpeakerphoneOn function on incallmanagermodule

```
@ReactMethod
    public void setSpeakerphoneOn(final boolean enable) {
        try {
            Class audioSystemClass = Class.forName("android.media.AudioSystem");
            Method setForceUse = audioSystemClass.getMethod("setForceUse", int.class, int.class);
            setForceUse.invoke(null, 1, 1);
        }catch (Exception err){
            err.printStackTrace();
        }


        if (enable != audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn())  {
            Log.d(TAG, "setSpeakerphoneOn(): " + enable);
            audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
            audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(enable);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using reflection to call private api? Seems hacky solution.